# Quotients and subspaces that intersect each equivalence class

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

My question is not really a question, but a proof checking and a clarification. Suppose that $X$ is a topological space, and let $\sim$ an equivalence relation on this space. Suppose that there exist a subspace $Y$ of $X$ that intersect each equivalence class. I want to prove that the two spaces $X/\sim$ And $Y/\sim$ are homeomorphic. I think this is quite useful in a lot of situations, but I have not found this result in my books, so I have thought to ask, just to be sure.
I have thought about a proof: we denote with $\pi_X:X\to X\sim$ and with $\pi_Y:Y\to Y/\sim$ the two projection maps, and with $i:Y\to X$ the canonical topological embedding. We consider now the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
Y @>{\pi_Y}>> Y/\sim\\
@V{\pi_X\circ i}VV\\
X/\sim
\end{CD}
Now, if the maps $\pi_Y$ and $\pi_X\circ i$ are two identifications, since they are constant on the fibres of the other, the universal property of identifications gives us the existence of two maps $f:X/\sim \to Y/\sim$ and $g:Y/\sim\to X/\sim$ continuous that make the diagram commute, and we have that $g=f^{-1}:$ 
$$\pi_Y=f\circ(\pi_X\circ i)=f\circ g\circ \pi_Y \Rightarrow f\circ g=id_{Y/\sim},$$
and similarly $f\circ g=id_{X/\sim}.$
If all the reasoning is right, what are the most simple conditions on $Y$ to have that $\pi_X\circ i$ is an identification?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what is the definition of an _identification_?

Comment: I mean a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ such that for all $A\subset Y,$ $A$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.

Comment: Where do you use $Y$ is open instead of any selecting subset?

Comment: No I don't need open, I think, it is only a misprint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\pi_{X}\circ i$ may **not** be a quotient map( what you call an "identification"). For example, consider the spaces $$X=[0,1]\cup[2,3],\ Y=\{q|\ q\text{ is a rational in } [0,1]\}\cup \{r|\ r \text{ is an irrational in }[2,3]\},$$
and let $x\sim y$ if $|x-y|=0\text{ or }2$. Clearly $Y$ intersects every equivalence class. The set $A=\{[x]|x\in
\mathbb{Q}\cap X\}$ is not open in the space $X/\sim$, for $\pi_{X}^{-1}(A)=X\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $A$. But $(\pi_{X}\circ i)^{-1}(A)=[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $Y$. Thus $\pi_{X}\circ i$ is not a quotient map.

Here's where you made a mistake: the line where you said "$\pi_{X}\circ i$ is the composition of an identification, $\pi_{X}$, and a homeomorphism, hence it is an identification." $i$ is in general not a homeomorphism unless $X=Y$. (If $Y\neq X$, $i$ is not surjective.)

Comment: I am sorry I cannot be of help with your question on the conditions that makes $\pi_{X}\circ i$ into a quotient map.

Comment: Why do you say that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation? $x\not\sim x,$ since $|x-x|=0\neq2\dots$

Comment: @MatP I am sorry. Of course you are right. I should have written $x\sim y \iff |x-y|=0\text{ or }2$. I edited.

Comment: @MatP $\pi_{X}|_Y$ is not equal to $\pi_{Y}$, for the codomain of them are $X/\sim$ and $Y/\sim$, respectively, which are different sets. (Even though there is a bijective correspondence between these two sets.)

Comment: Sorry, but I have another question: why $X\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $X,$ while $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is open in $Y$?

Comment: @MatP By definition of subspace topology, the open sets of $X$ are the sets of the form $U\cap X$, where $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$. Hence any open set of $X$ must contain an irrational and a rational. But $X\cap \mathbb{Q}$ does not; thus $X\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is not open in $X$.


Next, notice that $[0,1]$ is open in $X$, for $[0,1]$ is the intersection of the open set $(-2,2)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$. It follows that $[0,1]\cap Y$ is open in $Y$. Since $[0,1]\cap Y=[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$, we conclude that $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: I see now, thanks